# Как работает || оператор в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#

```
var obj = {};

var x = obj.zz || 2; // почему эта строчка так срабатывает?

alert(x); // выводит 2
```

`obj.zz == undefined` это понятно, поэтому он вычисляет второй аргумен 2, но почему результат выражения кладётся в x?

Почему он туда не `true` кладёт, если операция булевская?

К чему вопрос возник. Ищу аналог `??` из C#.

```
int? pageFromUrl;
int page = pageFromUrl ?? 1;
```

Правильно ли я понимаю что `obj.zz || 2` из JavaScript это аналог `obj.zz ?? 2` из C#?

Comment: `||` - говорит, что нужно вернуть тот элемент, который не falsy.... 2 - это  не falsy, вот 0 - это falsy..... сравни `if (0) console.log(111); else console.log(222);` и `if (2) console.log(111); else console.log(222);`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ага, понятно, спасибо, оформите как ответ?

Comment: если  что-то приводится к true, то почему бы его не вернуть в качестве true :)

Comment: не. надо более корректно мысли выражать. а я на это сейчас не способен

Comment: @splash58 тогда понятно почему в JavaScript нет `??` опрератора, его реально полностью заменяет `||`, что я и хотел узнать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из спецификации.

> Note: the value produced by a && or || operator is not necessarily of type Boolean. The value produced will always be the value of one of the two operand expressions.

По-русски.

> Заметьте: значение, возвращаемое опретором && или опретором || не обязательно типа Boolean. Однако это значение всегда будет одного типов операндов.

Что это значит?

```
false || true
```

Вернет `true`.

```
false || 1
```

Вернет `1`

```
0 || "str"
```

Вернет `str`

При этом если оба операнда - thruthy, то вернется первый из них:

```
true || 1
```

Вернет `true`

А если оба операнда - falthy, то вернется последний:

```
false || 0
```

Вернет `0`

---

> Почему он туда не true кладёт, если операция булевская?

Верно подмечено, на самом деле. Но то, что операция логическая не значит, что и возвращаемое значение будет представлено Boolean значением, как видно из примеров выше и как указано в спецификации.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, как я понимаю, это еще один из "трюков" js:

```
a = a || 0
```

превратит `a` из любого "falsey"-значения в 0 (извините, даже не представляю, как это правильно перевести.

При этом, к falssey значениям отноcятся:

- `false`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `0`
- `""` (empty string)
- `NaN` (not a Number)